# Selenium Click fails to click on elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

We have updated to the most recent Selenium version 3.141.59 and have found that clicks do not work. I don't get an error message indicating that the click failed and moves on to the next function or line. I have verified that it’s not working on Chrome, Firefox, and Edge. Our code is written in Java.

ChromeDriver: 73.0.3683.68
Geckodriver: 0.24
Microsoft WebDriver: 6.17134

Things that I have tried but still fail:

1. Adding a wait time before clicking on the element
2. Actions
3. JavaScriptExecutor

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post html or url? and also mention which element wants to click?

Comment: I can't give you the url but I can give you the element html <div class="portal-option-next-btn" onclick="instantCall();" title="Click to proceed to next step!">Next</div>

Comment: may I know which language are you trying python or java?

Comment: I am coding in Java

Answer (score 0):

As per your `div` element I am able to get the text value with following `Xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='portal-option-next-btn'][text()='Next']")));
System.out.println(element.getText());      
WebElement element1 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='portal-option-next-btn' and @title='Click to proceed to next step!']")));
System.out.println(element1.getText());
```

Please check if there any `frame` available.If you have any frame then you have to switch to `frame` first to access the element.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("Frame-name");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have any frames. I did a search just in case to make sure I don’t have any iframes on the page and I didn’t see any. But I will try to see if it will grab the text and let you know what the results were.

Comment: I did as you suggested, and I am unable to get the text from the element.

Comment: No I am not, I can see it filling out the form but its not clicking on the next button.

Comment: I am really in dark why isn’t working.if you come on chat and share me url I might help you.

Comment: Yeah so am I, I can't share the url with you it would be going against company policy to do that. My hands are tied in that regard.